# Does XAML contain a subset of html tags?

Tags: xaml

I know that there are lot of tags in XAML that have simmilar names in html. Is this because XAML contains all of the tags that html does, or is it just coincidence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No XAML and HTML are completely different.   XAML tags map to .NET objects and properties.
There are some XAML tags named similarly to mimic document functionality, like `<Paragraph>`, `<Bold>`, but the top of my head, I actually can't think of many that are exactly the same.  Are you sure you aren't refering to XHTML?

Comment: I am referring to XAML, not XHTML. I've just noticed that there are alot of name simmilarities and wanted to know if the XAML developers "stole" everything from good ole html into XAML name and all.